# Salesforce Flow Quick Choice default value

Tags: visual-workflow, screen-flow, default-value

I have a Salesforce Flow with a [Quick Choice component](https://unofficialsf.com/quick-choice-improved-picklists-and-radio-buttons-for-flow/). and would like to populate it with a *default value*.

[image]

For the data source I setup two string collections (labels and  values):
[image]

When I debug the Flow the default value is not been populated, even-though the variable does have a value.

[image]

Variable value:

[image]

If I hardcode that Id value on the Quick Choice default setup: "0038b000033OvaBAAS" without quotes,

[image]

it seams to work. }

[image]

But I need it to work with the variable, not hardcoding.

Any ideas?